# Lay nodes out in circle

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to layout my nodes like this:
[image: //TODO Insert picture here]
Here is my current layout, called `CircularPane`:

```
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.VPos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;

public class CircularPane extends Pane {
    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        final int radius = 50;
        final double increment = 360 / getChildren().size();
        double degreese = 0;
        for (Node node : getChildren()) {
            double x = radius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(degreese)) + getWidth() / 2;
            double y = radius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(degreese)) + getHeight() / 2;
            layoutInArea(node, x - node.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth() / 2, y - node.getBoundsInLocal().getHeight() / 2, getWidth(), getHeight(), 0.0, HPos.LEFT, VPos.TOP);
            degreese += increment;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my main class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        CircularPane pane = new CircularPane();
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            Button button = new Button("" + i);
            pane.getChildren().add(button);
        }
        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

And here is my current display:

[image]

The nodes are not at the bottom touching, they are equally spread out around the circle. I want to make it so they go to the bottom, but can't figure out how to.

Comment: I don't really get what the question is.. What do you have already? What do you want to get and what is wrong with what you already have?

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: I want to layout the nodes like in the picture at the top, I am trying to figure out how to do that.

Comment: So what is wrong with the picture that you already have? That the circle is missing?

Comment: @vefthym That the nodes are not at the bottom touching, they are equally spread out around the circle. I want to make it so they go to the bottom, but can't figure out how to.

Comment: OK, please add that comment to the question

Comment: @EduardoDennis Look at the notes on the picture, they should be touching.

Comment: It should almost look like that each node is attached to a string which is attached to the center of the circle and "gravity" is pulling them to the bottom. Of course, not taking into consideration that the objects would rotate.

Comment: @CaptainMan `layoutInArea` is inherited from `Region`, that is all the code from `CircularPane`, I have a few constants such as `radius`, I intend to put those in some other methods when this gets put to use.

Comment: Oops. Coffee hasn't kicked in, looks like those are from javafx libary, ignore my earlier comment.

Comment: Well, just do it, no? Start with the node(s) in the middle of the list, position them, and then just work to the left and to the right and position the other nodes accordingly, so they touch (or leave the required gap). Surely it's just a little trigonometry.

Comment: @James_D I am only in Algebra 2, I think I have a good idea of what is required of this, but I think it needs tangent, not really good at that.

Comment: Algebra 2 + the trig you've already shown you know should be pretty much enough.

Comment: It's the point where the two nodes collide is what I am having troubles with, I have it written out on a paper in front of me, trying to figure out how to calculate that. Not sure how to though. Another problem is what if the node count is even, there is no bottom node then.

Comment: If you know the location of one node (node `k`), say its center is at `(x_k, y_k)`, relative to the center of the circle, then if the next node (`k+1`) is positioned so it is to the left and the vertical edges touch, then `x_(k+1) = x_k - (w_k + w_(k+1)) / 2`, where `w_k` is the width of node `k`, etc. On the other hand if it is positioned so the horizontal edges touch you have `y_(k+1) = y_k - (h_k + h_(k+1))/2`. If `t` is the angle, in the first case you have `cos(t)=x_(k+1)/R`, in the 2nd, `sin(t)=y_(k+1)/R`. Then just choose the smallest angle and use `x^2 +y^2 =R^2` (R = radius).

Comment: If there are an odd number of nodes, you can first position the "middle" one so its center is at the bottom of the circle. If there are an even number, you can position the middle two, with `x=-w/2` for the left one and `x=w/2` for the right one; again use `x^2 + y^2 = R^2` to get `y` when you have `x`. Then use the above to position all the other nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach to layout the buttons over a circle is correct, but in this line you are defining how they will be layouted:

```
final double increment = 360 / getChildren().size();
```

This gives the same angle between any two buttons refered from the center of the circle! And that's why you get your current display.

If you want to layout the nodes like in your figure, if I get it right, these are the conditions:

- Every node has its center over the circle
- The nodes are equally separated in horizontal: the horizontal gap goes from 0 to some value.
- The initial gap from the circle to the first node goes from 0 to some value.
- The size of each node may be adjusted to fulfill the previous conditions

So let's define some fields for those values, and adjust the size of the pane:

```
class CircularPane extends Pane {

    private final double radius;
    private final double ext_gap;
    private final double int_gap;

    public CircularPane(double radius, double ext_gap, double int_gap){
        this.radius=radius;
        this.ext_gap=ext_gap;
        this.int_gap=int_gap;

        setMinSize(2*radius, 2d*radius);
        setPrefSize(2*radius, 2d*radius);
        setMaxSize(2*radius, 2d*radius);
    }
}
```

And now, given any `n` buttons, the above conditions can be turned into one single equation that solves the size of the node. If the total available length (`2*radius`) minus two exterior gaps (`2*ext_gap`) is the same as n buttons of size `buttonSize` and `n-1` interior gaps (`int_size`), then, the size of every button has to be:

```
@Override
protected void layoutChildren() {
    int n=getChildren().size();
    double buttonSize = (2*radius-2*ext_gap-(n-1)*int_gap)/n;
}
```

Finally, now you can set the size of the button and layout every node, just by increasing the `x` coordinate (by the size of the button plus an inner gap), and then getting the `y` coordinate from the circle equation:

```
@Override
protected void layoutChildren() {
    int n=getChildren().size();
    double buttonSize = (2*radius-2*ext_gap-(n-1)*int_gap)/n;

    double x=ext_gap+buttonSize/2d, y;            
    for (Node node : getChildren()) {
        ((Button)node).setMinSize(buttonSize, buttonSize);
        ((Button)node).setPrefSize(buttonSize, buttonSize);
        ((Button)node).setMaxSize(buttonSize, buttonSize);

        node.setStyle("-fx-font-size: "+Math.round(buttonSize/3));
        node.setManaged(false);

        y=getHeight()/2d+Math.sqrt(radius*radius-Math.pow(x-radius,2d));

        layoutInArea(node, x-buttonSize/2d, y-buttonSize/2d, getWidth(), getHeight(), 0.0, HPos.LEFT, VPos.TOP);

        x+=buttonSize+int_gap;
    }

}
```

Note that you can also change the size of the font, to get a visible number for any size of the button.

Note also that `node.setManaged(false);` avoids the calls to `layoutChildren()` when you click the buttons (due to changes in the size of the clicked button when being focused or clicked).

Finally this will create the circular pane and draw a circle:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    CircularPane pane = new CircularPane(200,20,10);
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        Button button = new Button("" + (i+1));
        pane.getChildren().add(button);
    }
    Circle circle = new Circle(200);
    circle.setFill(null);
    circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    StackPane stack=new StackPane(circle,pane);
    Scene scene = new Scene(stack, 500, 500);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

With this result:

[image: CirclePane]

Comment: Nice explanation! With some thought, I figured that my question does not accurately reflect what I wanted to do. I over thought it! I think I can figure it out on my own though, it's really hard to understand they way components are layed out in JavaFX, you can't just say, `setX()` like you could in Swing. I will mark this as the answer to the question though. Stuff like having to cast the nodes to Button, and having to set the size of them constant.